# How to match the content with regex

Tags: regex

I have regex as `it\(((.|\n)+?)\[8032\]`

and the content as

```
it(`some text
   some text - [208]`, async () => {
    expect(0).toBe(2);
});



it('some text ' +
    'some text - [8032]', async () => {
    expect(1).toBe(0);
});
```

Now if I execute the regex

I just want

```
it('some text ' +
    'some text - [8032]
```

but unfortunately, I am getting a larger match as

```
it(`some text
   some text - [208]`, async () => {
    expect(0).toBe(2);
});

it('some text ' +
    'some text - [8032]
```

Comment: To be clear, you want the text where inside the square brackets, there is exactly **8032**?

Comment: @CoffeehouseCoder No I want full line as shown which starts from it to the [8032]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a negative look ahead `(?!it)` with `(.|\n)+?` so it rejects the larger match which contains `it` text and hence you need to use this regex,

```
it\((((?!it\(')(.|\n))+?)\[8032\]
```

Here in your own regex, the only addition I have done is this `(?!it)` which makes sure, the selected string does not contain `it` within it.

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nQH10A/4)**

Comment: I had used `it` text to reject the match as that was enough as per your data. If you think `it` can appear in your intended text, then we need to choose a text larger than `it` which should be able to reject the match. So you can add `(` after it and use this regex `it\((((?!it\()(.|\n))+?)\[8032\]` Let me update my answer as well.

Comment: Yeah thanks, It works well now, But there's some additions as well like ',`,"

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
it\([^\[]+?\[8032\]['\"]
```

As shown here: **https://regex101.com/r/G95JCw/1/**

## Explanation -

`[^\[]+` tells the regex to match all characters **except '['** until it reaches the desired [8032] - which solves your issue about the previous text also being selected.
`['\"]` at the end is just to select the last quotation marks before async. This part is not needed, but it makes the extraction a bit easier for you :)

Comment: You are correct and thanks for the efforts but I might get [ in between the text as well, I am accepting the second answer but upvoted this.

Comment: @AjaySuwalka Which answer you choose is completely your decision, but I noticed that the other answer won't work if there is an `it` in the text. Isn't that a much more likely possibility than a square bracket in the text? You can see what I'm talking about here: **https://regex101.com/r/nQH10A/2**

Comment: Oh Sorry, I get your point and that's bad (facepalm), Can you please give me another choice with your regex in case if it has [ in the text?

Comment: @AjaySuwalka I'm working on another version right now, it'll probably be ready in 15 minutes or so :)

Comment: @AjaySuwalka I think I've done it. Check this out: https://regex101.com/r/G95JCw/2

Comment: @RoboMop: Your solution won't work if the first block of string is not there and also lookbehind is not supported in many flavours of regex. [Check this](https://regex101.com/r/G95JCw/3)